# Alias javascript object increase memory?

Tags: javascript

Some one can tell me when i do copy/alias a JavaScript object, does this increase memory consumption?

sample: I want to shortcut to some object.

```
// total memory 12k
// object.someobject 12k
var a = object.someobject;
```

**Q1.**
How much memory (24k? or 12k)

```
// and if i do
// object2 10k
var b = object2;
var c = $.extend(a,b);
```

**Q2.**
How many my memory now?

**Q3.**
If i do that it increase memory, what best practice to shortcut object

**-- EDIT --**

**Q4.** What happen if i delete or set a to null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe in jQuery's implementation of `extend` `a` and `c` will be the same object.

`b`s properties are copied to `a` (by reference) so the memory increase is only very minor; just `b`s keys in `a`.

In code:

```
var a = { "foo": {} }; // memory: defining a,
var b = { "bar": {} }; // memory: defining b
var c = $.extend(a, b); // memory: adding key 'bar' to `a`
c === a; // true
a.bar === b.bar; // true
({}) === ({}); // false (for sanity)
```

Comment: Q4. What happen if i delete or set `a` to `null`;

Comment: Then `c` will still point to the extended object. If you also set `c` to `null` then the object will get garbage collected (assuming no other references exist).

Comment: Just an add-on:`$.extend(a,b)` can be used without being inside a var,since it will simply update `a` with `b` contents. Since it's used inside a var, it will return the updated `a`,that's why `a` and `c` are equal (and pointing to the same memory address!). By the way,you can't `delete a`, because `delete` is meant for properties (remember `a` is a copy of `object.someobject`, not the actual object). And if you use `delete object.someobject`, `someobject` that will be deleted, not the entire object. And `a` will still be pointing to the memory that *still* holds `object.someobject` value.